# Is duck typing valid to identify parts of speech?

Tags: parts-of-speech, morphological-analysis

Let's say we're trying to identify a word or a phrase and on the surface it seems a bit strange and to not fit into an easily identified category/part of speech (POS).

Is it valid to say "If it walks like a duck and quacks like a duck then it is a duck", for the purpose of identifying its category?

E.g. "Phrase X" can go anywhere that a POS "Y" can go, therefore "phrase X" *is* a POS "Y". "Phrase X" walks like a duck and quacks like a duck (the duck being a POS "Y") so it is a duck.

- Wikipedia: [Duck typing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing)
- Wikipedia: [Duck test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_test)

Comment: Isn't that circular reasoning? If you already know that it "can go anywhere that a POS "Y" can go" then X is, has, becomes (depending on your framework) a Y. The problem is: "can go" is not defined; It's the question you are trying to answer.

Comment: Yes, it's valid. That is exactly how linguists identify the POS of a word.  Does the word occur in just those positions where words you know to be nouns (e.g.) occur?  If so, it must be a noun.

Comment: @GregLee That should be posted as an answer.

Comment: I disagree. In, for example, "Over a year was spent on the project", the subject "over a year" is in the position where a noun would typically occur, but "over a year" is a PP not an NP.

Comment: @BillJ That's the reverse of what I'm asking. Does "over a year" fit where other PPs fit? If yes, it is also a PP. It doesn't matter if NPs can sometimes fit as well if there are cases where they don't fit.

Comment: I disagree, but in any case was actually responding to Greg's comment.

Comment: @BillJ You disagree that that was what I was asking, or you disagree with the premise of my question? If the second, an answer from you would probably be helpful.

Answer (score -1):

In the dynamicly typed programming languages I know, duck typing means you have an object with a well defined interface, properties with certain names, that are passed along with the object into other functions, which barf when trying to call back a property that's not there. So every object that supplies a method *toInteger(X)* can be treated like an integer, so e.g. 1+'a' == 50 in most codes, but they disagree on how to form "a1" from 'a' and 1; some allow 'a'+1, some don't, which depends on how the operator is defined, which isn't always implemented as property, but as built-in function.

---

Equivalently, people frequently barf upon interpreting "Alice, Bob and me". Some employ type coercion, applying *toSubject* on the fly, others say that's inefficient, who prefer to be strict and test *isSubject*

Similarly, even native speakers quarrel about the number inflection for *to be* after conjunctions of various number (a paper and three publications [is/are]) because they are not sure what the highly polysemous *and* does.

---

So, no, from a descriptive stand point you cannot decide simply from observation when you observe contradictory situations.